# File sharing in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

I have a peer-to-peer network and use Windows 7 for my workstations.

If I share a drive in Windows 7, when I want to access it I get the following error dialog:

> **Network Error**
>   Windows cannot access \USER01-PC\d
>
> You do not have permission to access \USER01-PC. Contact your Network
>   Administrator to request access.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Are you the administrator of the workstation? Or do you have UAC turned on? And are you within a domain?

Comment: I am Administrator
And I donot have domain
what is UAC and how turn on it?

Comment: Please associate your Stack Overflow account with your account here (in user options), to regain ownership other your original question, which has been migrated here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user you are authenticating as must have BOTH read rights to the share and read rights to the folder/files of that share. (Assuming you are sharing on an NTFS drive).

Go to the folder, and grant "Everyone" full control of the shared folder. (Later change this to "modify" if everything works)

[image: [Permissions dialogue image]]

(Grabbed image from google images; you should select "Everyone" ideally. If it's not in the list, hit "Add..." then type "Everyone". Once this works, you may want to consider limiting access to local users)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following, but please note you make changes to the registry at your own risk:

1. Go to your Start Menu and press 'Run'.

   - If you do not have Run in your Start Menu you can find the Run program in your Programs folder, then select Accessories and choose Run from that list.
2. Type in ‘regedit’ and press OK.
3. Search for the following location:

   ```
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa
   ```
4. Double click on `'everyoneincludesanonymous'` and change the value data to 1.
5. Double click on `'NoLmHash'` and change the value data to 0.
6. Search for the following location:

   ```
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\LanmanServer\Parameters
   ```
7. Double click on `'restrictnullsessaccess'` and change the value data to 0.
8. Close the Registry Editor.
9. Restart your PC.

Comment: I Use This Steps But Can Not Fix this Problem

Answer (score 1):

Does the user you're logged in with has a password? Make sure it has one, as Windows blocks accounts with blank passwords by default.